# Dynamic User Defined Tables PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, database-design

I'm working on Laravel based application and need to do the following:

End user should be able create, modify, view and delete their own custom tables and search them using the UI

Relations can also be defined between those tables

For example in PHP I would like to do something like this:

`DynamicTable::create('Customers', ['ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Phone']);`

User shouldn't have control over the database, rather they should easily build their own custom data and structure without technical knowledge.

Looking for recommendations for what database and architecture would be scalable and ideal

Comment: I'm thinking this is probably an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). There is probably a better way to achieve your end goal. To do this, you'd essentially have to recreate a program like phpMyAdmin, and a way for the users to write PHP code directly into the site, which seems to me like way too much control going to the user.

Comment: EAV schema is very customizable, but the performance is bad when the table gets big.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could try a `document/nosql` database for this. I don’t recommend SQL with such approach, as it defeats the purpose of the structure it offers and would be hard to keep safe.

For example:
https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained

Features and use-cases, especially the one you are asking for:

*While the example above highlights the differences in data models between relational databases and NoSQL databases, many other important differences exist, including:*

- ***Flexibility of the schema***
- *Scaling technique*
- *Support for transactions*
- *Reliance on data to object mapping*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do users need to create a custom table or just store custom data? Giving users access to create custom tables/schema directly seems a bit risky?

Would it not be better to store the user defined schema in JSON on mysql JSON column that can then be queried?

As for how you would achieve this with laravel I would imagine you would need to construct your own service class similar to something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

class CustomTableService {

   public function create(string $name, array $columns): bool {
       Schema::create($name, function(Blueprint $table) use ($columns) {
           foreach($columns as $name => $type)
           {
               $table->addColumn($type, $name);
           }
       });
   }

}
```

Comment: FYI I don't recommend you do this, it is way to much control for the user to have and you will have no control over database performance, indexing, data modeling etc etc. This is an example of how you would do it, I would recommend you not do it.